# Stylish-Portfolio Template Dropdown Menu not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I copied  the template from `https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-stylish-portfolio` but the drop-down menu isn't working on my machine. The javascript and stylesheet files were not touched or edited, the home page code can be viewed at `https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-stylish-portfolio/blob/master/index.html`. 
Below is my code:

**APP/VIEWS/LAYOUT/APPLICATION.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TestApp</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic',  media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <script src="vendor/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'custom', 'vendor' %> 
  </head>
  <body id="page-top">
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

**APP/VIEWS/MAIN/_NAVIGATION.HTML.ERB**

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<a class="menu-toggle rounded" href="#">
  <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
</a>
<nav id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <ul class="sidebar-nav">
    <li class="sidebar-brand">
      <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
      <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
      <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
      <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
      <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
      <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**CONFIG/WEBPACK/ENVIROMENT.JS**

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require("webpack")

environment.plugins.append("provide", new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))

module.exports = environment
```

**APP/JAVASCRIPT/PACKS/APPLICATION.JS**

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("bootstrap")
require("jquery/jquery.min.js")

require.context('../images', true)


document.addEventListener("turbolink:load", () => {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

**APP/JAVASCRIPT/PACKS/CUSTOM.JS**

```
import "../../../vendor/assets/javascript/stylish-portfolio.min.js"
```

**APP/JAVASCRIPT/PACKS/VENDOR.JS**

```
import "../../../vendor/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
import "../../../vendor/assets/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: When you say `isn't working on my machine` what do you mean exactly?

Comment: It just reloads with an `/#` in the ip address.

Comment: Can you verify that the javascript files are actually being loaded into the page by inspecting it?

Comment: Seems the javascripts file been uploaded by application.js, vendor.js and custom.js are all the same, which i dont think should be so.

Comment: Considering this fact, I don't think the javascript files are loading properly.